# Can application config be loaded in a scala macro?

Tags: scala, configuration, scala-macros

I'm attempting to write a macro that depends on some information in my Play application's configuration. I'd like to use some configuration generate the tree in the macro implementation.

When I attempt to load that configuration in the macro, I see an error that no configuration setting was found:

```
Error:(80, 16) exception during macro expansion: 
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'auth-service'
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:156)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:174)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:188)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:193)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getObject(SimpleConfig.java:268)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getObject(SimpleConfig.java:41)
    at mac.MyMacro$.mImpl(MyMacro.scala:16)
      MyMacro.m()
```

When using the same config loading code in the test case, everything loads fine.

My macro looks like this:

```scala
object MyMacro {

  def m(): List[Int] = macro MyMacro.mImpl

  def mImpl(c: Context)() = {

    import c.universe._

    ConfigFactory.load().getObject("auth-service") // this fails

    q"""
         List(1, 2)
       """
  }
}
```

And the test that's attempting to execute it looks like this:

```scala
    "test macro" in {
      ConfigFactory.load().getObject("auth-service") // this succeeds
      MyMacro.m()
    }
```

Can you please help me understand why the application config isn't being loaded or isn't available within the macro? If it's not possible to load config this way, what is a common way to solve a problem like this where a macro depends on some declared configuration?

Comment: A **macro** runs at _compile-time_ and a **cofiguration** is obtained a _runtime_. This won't work, it is conceptually wrong.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez It's perfectly possible to obtain configuration at the runtime of the macro which is the compile-time of the application (of course, changing the configuration after compilation will have no effect).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov yeah I know but then what is the point of having to load the config, just read from some object with default values. My point was that the problem seems conceptually wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Macros need to be defined in a separate project; `ConfigFactory.load()` in that project will look for configuration files in the classpath of that project, and not of the project which uses the macro. So if you can, the part of the configuration used by the macro should live in that project.

Alternatively, you can use one of the [`ConfigFactory.parseFile()` overloads](https://lightbend.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory.html#parseFile-java.io.File-) to pass a specific file, but then your macro needs to know the path to the application.

Comment: Ah I see, I'll give it a try and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't see this part of the documentation before but there it is. "The separate compilation restriction requires macros to be placed in a separate project." 
Adding a link here in case it helps someone.
https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html#using-macros-with-maven-or-sbt

Comment: So I was able to give it a try. I created an sbt subproject and strangely I ended up with the same error.

Error:(24, 16) exception during macro expansion: 
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: merge of system properties,reference.conf @ jar:file:/Users/luke.eller/Library/Application%20Support/IntelliJIdea2019.3/Scala/lib/jps/incremental-compiler.jar!/reference.conf: 1: No configuration setting found for key 'auth-service'